# Electron vue require is not defined

Tags: vue.js, electron, require

I am developing an electron vue desktop app, but when I do run start there is error in my console mentioning :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at db.js:1
index.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index.html:14
semantic.min.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at semantic.min.js:11
```

I have researched a lot and i npm installed browserify, but it did not work. Then I found the nodeintegration is by default set to false and enabling it to true solved the error for many

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    
    width:1024, height:800,webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}
});
```

But this gave me different error below:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'D:\vueproject\bookmarking-app-electron-vuejs-sqlite- 
master\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v9.1-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- D:\vueproject\bookmarking-app-electron-vuejs-sqlite-master\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3- 
binding.js
- D:\vueproject\bookmarking-app-electron-vuejs-sqlite-master\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js
- D:\vueproject\bookmarking-app-electron-vuejs-sqlite-master\index.html
at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797)
at Function.i._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:42)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852)
```

My index.html is rendered, however the vue components is not being loaded perhaps due to this error. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you `npm install`?

Comment: Yes, I did already

Comment: Can you show us the package.json please?